# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app OneDrive simple upload file results in class not registered exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I'm trying to implement a simple app that uploads a photo onto the user's OneDrive.

Using myself as the guinea pig, I'm able to successfully create folder named after my application but I run into an exception with I try to upload a file.

Here's the code:

```
var connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);

                        string skyDriveFolder = await LiveExtensions.CreateDirectoryAsync(connectClient, "LumpyCircles", "me/skydrive");

                        StorageFile file = await local.GetFileAsync("lumpyCircle.png");
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            //LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await connectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(skyDriveFolder, "LumpyCircle.png", file, OverwriteOption.Rename);
                            var task = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive", "lumpyCircle.png", file, OverwriteOption.Rename);
                            await task.StartAsync();
                        }
```

And the exception + stack trace is:

$exception  {System.Exception: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader.CreateUpload(Uri uri, IStorageFile sourceFile)
   at Microsoft.Live.Operations.CreateBackgroundUploadOperation.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__4(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()}   System.Exception

Other notable information:

- WindowsPhone 8.1 device (OS: 8.10.14192.280 (dev preview))
- App is WP 8.1 Silverlight
- Live SDK version is 5.6
- The file being uploaded is a png file
- I've verified that the folder is indeed created on my onedrive and this exception also occurs on the emulator.

Banging my head on the wall here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a little further. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631823.aspx, there are two ways of adding a reference to the Live SDK. The first one involves selecting Live SDK from Windows Phone 8.1 > Extensions (under references). The second one involves selecting Microsoft.Live and Microsoft.Live.Controls from Assemblies > Extensions.

The first one does not work. As I mentioned in the original description, I can create a directory but I can not upload files into it.

The second option does work. I am able to upload files with no problems. The only issue is that I cannot make use of single sign-on using this method

Answer (score 0):

In your Package.appxmanifest file, check the "Internet (Client & Server)" capability.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#internetandpublicnetworks